# Is there a way to increment all fields in a Redis hash at once?

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis to cache a large amount of highly dynamic counters. In my case users are subscribing to sources and I want to cache each user's counter for that source. When a new item arrives at the source it's natural that the counters for all users subscribed to this source should be incremented by `1`. Some sources have hundreds of thousands of subscribers, so it's important that this happens immediately.

However, Redis doesn't have a native method to increment all hash fields at once, only [HINCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/hincrby). Is there a solution for this?

While searching, I stumbled upon [some](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/923) [threads](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13832244) where people wanted a bulk version of `HINCRBY`, but my case is different. I want to increment **all** fields in the hash.

Comment: Did you try working with LUA? https://redis.io/commands/eval https://redis.io/commands/evalsha

Comment: Looks like a promising lead, though I'm a bit concerned about performance. I will probably call this 50-100 times per seconds and from what I read, lua scripts block the whole server until they are executed, so this could lead to contention.

Comment: Are you calling all these 100 times in one call? If not it shouldn't impact too much, you should try it

Comment: No, they could all be coming in parallel from different processes, even different servers. At the same time I need redis to be able to respond as fast as possible to clients that wants to fetch counters. I expect no less than 5000 gets per second from clients, probably above 10000.

Comment: Single redis should be easily hold such numbers if for some reason it doesn't you might want to consider clustering (see: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial or https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/)

Answer (score 0):

Such operation should be achieved by using LUA script see:

- https://redis.io/commands/evalsha
- https://redis.io/commands/eval

You can use LUA script to "batch" couple of operations on a single hash